Filter Table, Export specific column headers and column range to CSV, and save
I want to filter a table range where Generate = "x" and copy range, non-contiguous column header and down, and paste into a new workbook and save.
Sub ExportNewReps()
'
'

    CurrentFile = "FieldOps.xlsm"
    NewFile = "O365_FieldOps_Import.csv"

    Workbooks.Add

' Save New Workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    
' Filter and copy range to new workbook
    Windows("FieldOps.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FieldOps").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>"
    Union(Range(Range("B1:E1"), Range("B1:E1").End(xlDown)), Range(Range("M1:N1"), Range("M1:N1").End(xlDown))).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows("O365_FieldOps_Import.csv").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:F").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows("FieldOps.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A93").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FieldOps").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub


Is FieldOps the file containing the code you posted?

Copy Specific Columns From Excel Table to New Workbook

Use Option Explicit at the top of each module. It will force you to declare all variables (Dim, Const) but will save you a lot of time by e.g. finding typos before run-time.
Avoid using Select and any flavors of Active. They are often unreliable and slow down the code.
Instead, use constants and variables and reference the objects to make the code more readable.

Source

In my case, the table FieldOps is found on sheet Sheet1 and starts in cell D6 illustrating the flexibility of the code.


Destination After the Line srg.Copy dcell

Destination Final (No formatting Due to .csv)

Option Explicit

Sub ExportNewReps()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' These two need to be in 'sync'.
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "O365_FieldOps_Import.csv"
    Const DST_FILE_FORMAT As Long = xlCSV
    
    ' Reference the source objects (workbook, worksheet, range...).
     
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, use the following instead.
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("FieldOps.xlsm")

    ' Assuming you don't know the name of the worksheet containing the table.
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = Application.Range("FieldOps").ListObject
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = slo.Parent
    ' Otherwise, use the following instead.
    'Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("FielOps")
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet columns to use with 'Intersect'
    ' to copy the required columns only.
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slo.Range.Range("B1:E1,M1:N1").EntireColumn
    ' i.e. reference the 2nd to 5th and the 14th to 15th TABLE column
    ' i.e. if the table start in column 'C', it means 2 columns
    ' to the right on the WORKSHEET.
    ' Move the table around and return the range address in the
    ' Immediate window (Ctrl+G) with...
    Debug.Print scrg.Address(0, 0)
    ' ... to better understand what the previous means.

    ' Reference the source range, the range to be copied.
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With slo
        ' Clear table filters.
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        ' Filter.
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" ' non-blanks in col 1
        ' Reference the correct range.
        Set srg = Intersect(scrg, .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        ' Clear table filters again.
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination objects (workbook, worksheet, range...).
    
    ' Add a single-worksheet ('xlWBATWorksheet') workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only!
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy.
    
    srg.Copy dcell
    
    ' Save and close.
    
    Dim dFilePath As String:
    dFilePath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & DST_FILE_NAME
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' i.e. overwrite without confirmation, don't show the dialog
    ' if different file format,...
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=DST_FILE_FORMAT
    ' if your list separator isn't the default comma, you might try to append
    ' ', Local:=True' to the previous line for the file to open correctly.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "New reps exported.", vbInformation

End Sub


Thanks @VBasic -- really appreciate the comments to help me understand what's going on.  Would you happen to know how I can save the export in my "C:\Temp" folder?
I've tried to save there a few different ways but receive errors

Near the top in the constants section, add the line Const DST_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Temp". Then replace swb.Path with  DST_FOLDER_PATH.

Thank you-- I'm not sure why my attempt to use save as wasn't working at first but it has finally worked out. Much appreciated!

Sometimes ( it works until it doesn't) there is an issue when referencing the most recently workbook added to the Workbooks Collection using ActiveWorkbook (don't do it, just posted an answer that is closely related). In this particular case, I used a variable ('bullet-proof') to prevent this issue from occurring Set dwb = Workbooks.Add. In the related answer, I couldn't use a variable so I used Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count) instead of ActiveWorkbook.
